# Failed to run model, -67108857, java.lang.NegativeArrayS izeException: -67108857

Tags: flutter, tensorflow, machine-learning

Has anyone solved this problem while using tflite package in flutter every model i used i get that issue of arrays?
Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(Failed to run model, -67108857, java.lang.NegativeArrayS
izeException: -67108857
How can i solve it.

Here is the basic code i was trying to run but landed into an error.

```html
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:tflite/tflite.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

import 'home.dart';
//import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

const String ssd = "SSD MobileNet";
const String yolo = "Tiny YOLOv2";

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Object Detection App',
      home: StaticImage(),
    );
  }
}

class StaticImage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _StaticImageState createState() => _StaticImageState();
}

class _StaticImageState extends State<StaticImage> {
  File _image;
  List _recognitions;
  bool _busy;
  double _imageWidth, _imageHeight;

  final picker = ImagePicker();

  // this function loads the model
  loadTfModel() async {
    await Tflite.loadModel(
      model: "assets/tflite/model_unquant.tflite",
      labels: "assets/tflite/label.txt",
    );
  }

  // this function detects the objects on the image
  detectObject(File image) async {
    var recognitions = await Tflite.detectObjectOnImage(
      path: image.path,       // required
      model: "SSDMobileNet",
      imageMean: 127.5,     
      imageStd: 127.5,      
      threshold: 0.4,       // defaults to 0.1
      numResultsPerClass: 10,// defaults to 5
      asynch: true          // defaults to true
    );
    FileImage(image)
        .resolve(ImageConfiguration())
        .addListener((ImageStreamListener((ImageInfo info, bool _) {
          setState(() {
            _imageWidth = info.image.width.toDouble();
            _imageHeight = info.image.height.toDouble();
          });
        }))); 
    setState(() {
      _recognitions = recognitions;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() { 
    super.initState();
    _busy = true;
    loadTfModel().then((val) {{
      setState(() {
        _busy = false;
      });
    }});
  }
  // display the bounding boxes over the detected objects
  List<Widget> renderBoxes(Size screen) {
    if (_recognitions == null) return [];
    if (_imageWidth == null || _imageHeight == null) return [];

    double factorX = screen.width;
    double factorY = _imageHeight / _imageHeight * screen.width;

    Color blue = Colors.blue;

    return _recognitions.map((re) {
      return Container(
        child: Positioned(
          left: re["rect"]["x"] * factorX,
          top: re["rect"]["y"] * factorY,
          width: re["rect"]["w"] * factorX,
          height: re["rect"]["h"] * factorY,
          child: ((re["confidenceInClass"] > 0.50))? Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(
                color: blue,
                width: 3,
              )
            ),
            child: Text(
              "${re["detectedClass"]} ${(re["confidenceInClass"] * 100).toStringAsFixed(0)}%",
              style: TextStyle(
                background: Paint()..color = blue,
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 15,
              ),
            ),
          ) : Container()
        ),
      );
    }).toList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    List<Widget> stackChildren = [];

    stackChildren.add(
      Positioned(
        // using ternary operator
        child: _image == null ? 
        Container(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("Please Select an Image"),
            ],
          ),
        )
      : // if not null then 
        Container(
          child:Image.file(_image)
        ),
      )
    );

    stackChildren.addAll(renderBoxes(size));

    if (_busy) {
      stackChildren.add(
        Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        )
      );
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Object Detector"),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: <Widget>[
          FloatingActionButton(
            heroTag: "Fltbtn2",
            child: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
            onPressed: getImageFromCamera,
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 10,),
          FloatingActionButton(
            heroTag: "Fltbtn1",
            child: Icon(Icons.photo),
            onPressed: getImageFromGallery,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child:Stack(
        children: stackChildren,
      ),
      ),
    );
  }
  // gets image from camera and runs detectObject
  Future getImageFromCamera() async {
    final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

    setState(() {
      if(pickedFile != null) {
        _image = File(pickedFile.path);
      } else {
        print("No image Selected"); 
      }
    });
    detectObject(_image);
  }
  // gets image from gallery and runs detectObject
  Future getImageFromGallery() async {
    final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    setState(() {
      if(pickedFile != null) {
        _image = File(pickedFile.path);
      } else {
        print("No image Selected");
      }
    });
    detectObject(_image);
  }
}
```

This is the code i was trying to run
[Image for error is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPOrK.png)

```html
name: ml_classifier
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  tflite: ^1.0.4
  image_picker: ^0.6.1+8
  image: ^2.1.4

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:
  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/tflite/model_unquant.tflite
    - assets/tflite/label.txt
```

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: yeah sure https://codecollab.io/@proj/MiddleAuthorityShell

Comment: Dont mind the .java i failed to find the right platform to share a dart code. @PayamAsefi

Comment: The problem might be from loading the model. did you add the models to your pubspec file?

Comment: yes i have done it multiple times, even when i used the same code or clone codes the others work with their model but when i put in mine i keep getting that error.

Comment: so the problem is probably from your model. In this case, it might be better to post your problem on their Github page.